# laravel-echo-server doesn't broadcast on events

Tags: php, laravel, redis, socket.io

I'm currently working chat webpage with laravel-echo-server package in Laravel, I'm trying to show a message to send a message to one user and receive that message in realtime, but when I send a message it loads in my chat but the other user doesn't receive anything until I refresh the site.
I think that laravel-echo-server isn't broadcasting correctly, but I don't know how to how to solve it.
I checked if the event was correctly executed and it does but I dont' receive nothing.
Can you help me?
I'm using redis has a broadcaster and it seems to work correctly I added it to .env as a `BROADCAST_DRIVER=redis` and `QUEUE_CONNECTION=redis`

ChatApp.vue

```
     ......
mounted() {
    console.log(this.user);
    Echo.private(`messages.${this.user.id}`)
     .listen('NewMessage', (e) => {
          console.log(e);
          if (this.selectedContact && e.message.from == this.selectedContact.id){
                    this.saveNewMessage(e.message);
                    alert('fired');
                }
      });
```

channels.php authenticate messages between users

```
Broadcast::channel('messages.{id}', function ($user, $id) {
    //dd($user->id, $id);
    var_dump($user);
    return (int) $user->id === (int) $id;
});
```

NewMessage.php This is my event

```
class NewMessage implements ShouldBroadcast
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithSockets, SerializesModels;

    public $message;

    /**
     * Create a new event instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct(Message $message)
    {
        $this->message = $message;
    }

    /**
     * Get the channels the event should broadcast on.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Broadcasting\Channel|array
     */
    public function broadcastOn()
    {
        return new PrivateChannel('messages.'.$this->message->to);
    }
    public function broadcastWith()
    {
        return ["message" => $this->message];
    }
}
```

ContactsController.php I use send fuction when I user send a message to a other user and after I broadcast

```
Im getting this in my terminal when a user send a message to other user but the other user doesn't receive noting until I refresh


C:\laragon\www\newchat
λ laravel-echo-server start

L A R A V E L  E C H O  S E R V E R

version 1.6.1

⚠ Starting server in DEV mode...

✔  Running at localhost on port 6001
✔  Channels are ready.
✔  Listening for http events...
✔  Listening for redis events...

Server ready!

[15:28:39] - Preparing authentication request to: http://newchat.test
[15:28:39] - Sending auth request to: http://newchat.test/broadcasting/auth

[15:28:40] - hq3MFtdUmFgfBB7WAAAA authenticated for: private-messages.2
[15:28:40] - hq3MFtdUmFgfBB7WAAAA joined channel: private-messages.2
[15:28:59] - Preparing authentication request to: http://newchat.test
[15:28:59] - Sending auth request to: http://newchat.test/broadcasting/auth

[15:29:00] - hf8Ginp5is-fyZLGAAAC authenticated for: private-messages.1
[15:29:00] - hf8Ginp5is-fyZLGAAAC joined channel: private-messages.1
Channel: chatapp_database_private-messages.7
Event: App\Events\NewMessage
...
class ContactsController extends Controller
{
    public function get()
    {
        $contacts = User::where('id', '!=' ,auth()->id())->get();
        return response()->json($contacts);
    }

    public function getMessagesFor($id)
    {
        $messages = Message::where('from', $id)->orWhere('to', $id)->get();
        return response()->json($messages);
    }
    public function send(Request $request)
    {
        $message = Message::create([
            'from' => auth()->id(),
            'to' => $request->contact_id,
            'text' => $request->text
        ]);
        broadcast(new NewMessage($message));
        return response()->json($message);
    }
}

...
```

Also Im using this command executed together with laravel-echo-server

```
 php artisan queue:listen --tries=1
```

Answer (score 0):

just add to your Event

```
 public function broadcastAs()
    {
        return 'message';
    }
```

then in listen .message

```
 Echo.private(`messages.${this.user.id}`)
     .listen('.message', (e) => {
          console.log(e);
          if (this.selectedContact && e.message.from == this.selectedContact.id){
                    this.saveNewMessage(e.message);
                    alert('fired');
                }
      });
```